# How to make a hardware device appear as an audio device while pairing?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want my hardware device to appear as a bluetooth audio device when pairing. Where and how should I set this property? To be more precise is it something i should do on hardware or something to be implemented in the programme that's running on the hardware?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the a2dp profile, this is what your device needs to provide

Comment: I do know about the profiles, i just have no idea how to implement it in the code

Comment: Here's a more deep explanation on my problem on what i have done so far.  
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164960/how-to-set-the-bluetooth-profile-to-hfp-when-connecting-to-a-device-in-android 
                                                                          but I'm just looking for a simple answer here on this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to use an android phone as an a2dp source, but someone else might